# Show all attachments, but if no attachments echo empty

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, the following is code that I have on category, and tag pages. It shows all the attachments of the 8 most recent posts, in a given category or tag. So if I'm on the 'cars' category page, it displays only photos from posts that were categorized as 'cars'. That part works great.

What I'm trying to do is get it so that even if there are several posts in that category, if none of those posts have attachments, it will echo something like, "sorry no photos here".

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

               <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    

 <?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 8, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

?> <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried adding an else statement, like this:

```
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>sorry no photos here</p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

However, if one post has a photo but the other doesn't it displays that one photo but it also echos the else statement.

Phew! Long explanation. This isn't life or death but I've spent so much time on it to no avail, I'm probably way more bugged by it than I should be. :/

Thanks in advance!

Wordpress source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments

Comment: Do this outside any Loops in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Your else is in the wrong place, it's acting as an else condition on have_posts() you need it to be an else condition on if ($attachments) like so:

```
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "sorry no photos here";
}
```

and if that doesn't work try:

```
if (count($attachments)>0) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "sorry no photos here";
}
```

Comment: Sadly, neither of them worked. :/ I really thought that the 2nd one would work.

I think it's because "attachments" represents whether or not posts were found and I'm just thinking there isn't a way to discern between having posts and having posts with attachments.

I removed the if and while statements and it work on the pages with no photos, it showed "no photos", but when I went to a page that should have photos it only showed the photo from the last post. both of your solutions worked the same in this regard.

Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you do `var_dump($attachments);` as the first line of the if and report back with your findings?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the power went out at my work...

So I did this:

```
if ($attachments) {
    var_dump($attachments);
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "sorry no photos here";
}
```

AND got this:

NULL array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#567 (32) { ["ID"]=> int(65) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2011-03-24 03:50:31" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2011-03-24 10:50:31" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(7) "Joe Ahn" ["show_in_menu"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_link"]=> string(1) "1" ["no_follow_link"]=> string(1) "0" ["alt_link_text"]=> NULL ["custom_link_class"]=> NULL ["redirect_url"]=> NULL ["target_blank"]=> string(1) "0" ["alt_title_attribute"]=> NULL ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(3) "ahn" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2011-03-24 03:50:31" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2011-03-24 10:50:31" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(64) ["guid"]=> string(66) "http://www.ouhsd.k12.ca.us/news/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ahn.jpg" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }

Comment: Oh and I should add that it showed all of this and only one photo, still the one from the last post.